# Azure Bicep giving InvalidTemplateDeployment error for Azure App Service Plan deployment

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-bicep

I'm trying to create App Service Plan using Bicep. I've created a full blown bicep script for the development infra and it is working fine. But for production when I'm executing the app Service plan module, I'm receiving the below error. I've almost spent a day for troubleshooting this issue. The module was also having bicep for deploying and configuring App Services. But for troubleshooting I've removed it. Kindly help me in identifying this issue.

*Main file*

```
@allowed([
  'aladdin'
])
@description('Environment Name')
param environmentPrefix string

@allowed([
  'uat'
  'prod'
])
@description('Environment Type')
param environmentType string
@allowed([
  'P1V3'
  'P2V3'
])
@description('App Services Plan SKU')
param appServicePlanSku string
var appRgName = 'rg-${environmentPrefix}-${environmentType}-ne-app01'
var appServicePlanName = 'asp-${environmentPrefix}-${environmentType}-ne-app01'

resource appResourceGroup 'Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups@2021-04-01' = {
  name: appRgName
  location: location
  tags: {
    environmentType: environmentType
    environmentPrefix: environmentPrefix
    role: 'Azure PAAS resources'
  }
}

module appServicePlan 'appServicePlan.bicep' = {
  scope: appResourceGroup
  name: 'appServicePlanModule'
  params: {
    appServicePlanName: appServicePlanName
    appServicePlanSku: appServicePlanSku
    location: location
  }
}
```

*Module*

```
param appServicePlanSku string
param appServicePlanName string
param location string

resource appServicePlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2022-03-01' = {
  name: appServicePlanName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: appServicePlanSku
    capacity: 1
  }
  kind: 'windows'
}
```

*Execucted using PowerShell*

```
New-AzSubscriptionDeployment `
    -Name Production `
    -Location northeurope `
    -TemplateParameterFile "$biceptemplate\main.parameters.json" `
    -TemplateFile "$biceptemplate\main.bicep" `
    -environmentPrefix 'aladdin' `
    -verbose
```

```
Error: Code=InvalidTemplateDeployment; Message=The template deployment 'Production' is not valid according to the validation procedure. The tracking id is ....
```

Comment: Can you please refer this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/495#issuecomment-871843616).?

Comment: No @AjayKumarGhose --- It did not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for your module:

```
param appServicePlanSku string
param appServicePlanName string
param location string

resource appServicePlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2022-03-01' = {
  name: appServicePlanName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: appServicePlanSku
    capacity: 1
  }
  kind: 'windows'
  properties: {}
}
```

Supplying an empty properties object on the resource.  It shouldn't be required but seems like it is in this case and bicep didn't flag it.  (issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues/784#issuecomment-1215717727))